# SQL table column "float" rounding to 6 figures

Tags: sql

I have a column with type "float", and it evidently is rounding to 6 figures.  So 23.123456 gets rounded to 23.1235..... and 12345678 gets rounded to 12345700

How do I prevent/change this?

Thanks

Comment: Just use data type with higher precision. Double, Decimal etc.

Comment: I am working since many years in the financial industry and from my experience I can say that I always had troubles with "float". It is just not useful (for the reasons others already explained) when it comes to precise numbers which are often critical depending on what you are doing. Since I figured out the many problems of float, we never used it again in any database and changed all floats to numeric. My advise: Don't be lazy, avoid using comfortable float, numeric takes a little bit more work but on the long run it's really worth (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Float (and Real for the sake of completeness) are approximate values. Please read on float point data types for instance [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912(v=sql.105).aspx)

If you need result of operations to be with higher precision , use numeric or decimal data types. From link above, in sql server,default maximum precision is 38. i.e. you will have up to 38 precise digits while performing calculations.

Comment: I see.  So I have quite a lot of data currently stored in a float column, and I need to convert it to decimal.  Should there be any issue if I simply change the column type?  Of course my previous data won't have the precision of decimal type, but that's fine.  I just want to make sure a float value of 123.456 doesn't turn into something like 999...  I tested this with a dummy column and it seemed to work alright.  Would you anticipate any issues with the existing data if I change the column type?

Comment: switching from float to numeric/decimal is pretty predictable. To learn details google for cast/convert operations for your RDBMS